# How exactly works the Javascript variable scope?

Tags: javascript, variables, scope

I am pretty new in JavaScript and I have some doubts related to the variable scope.

So I tryed to do this example:

```
function outer() {

    alert("INTO outer()");
    var val1 = 1;

    inner();

    alert(val2);
}

function inner() {
    alert("INTO inner()");

    val2 = 2;


}

outer();
```

In this simple example the **outer()** function is perform, in this function I call the **inner()** function that declare and initializes the **val2** variable. Then come back to the **outer()** function and from here I access and print the **val2** value.

So it seam to me that in Javascript I can access to the variable defined in the inner function from the outer function but I can't access to the variable declared in the outer function from the inner function.

Is it true? If it is true why this choose?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The declaration in your "inner" function is missing the `var` keyword. That makes `val2` a **global** symbol.

Answer (score 3):

It is true..The use of var in function 'outer'  makes val1 local variable whereas val2 of function 'inner' has global scope since the keyword var is not used.